# Copy a container's item to a window Extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I have an item inside a container in my Viewport, I want to copy that item to a new window: What I've tried copies the item to the new window but unfortunately it destroys it in the container.

How can I keep it in both places ?

```
 onOpenNewClick: function () {
    var win;
    var viewport = this.getMyViewport();
    var chart = viewport.down('container #thechart');

    win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
        title: 'Layout Window',
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        constrain: true,
        constrainHeader: true,
        hidden: false,
        shadow: false,
        maximizable: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        title: 'test',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            region: 'center',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'chart',
            xtype: chart
        }]
    });
    win.show()
    win.center();
},
```

My viewport :

```
items: [{
            region : 'center',
            height : '100%',
            items : [{
                        xtype : 'container',
                        id : 'pan_chart',
                        border : false,
                        autoHeight : true,
                        hidden : true,
                        autoScroll : true,
                        items : [{
                            width : screen.width,
                            xtype: 'mychart', 
                            id : 'thechart',

                        }]
                    }]
        }
        ]
```

Comment: I didn't understand your purpose. Please be more specific. For instance, what you want to copy?

Comment: I want to copy the container's item

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the object instead of copying. Because when you copy you copy the reference and not creating a new instance of the object.

[This thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?26644-Ext.ux.clone%28%29-Object-or-Array-cloning-function) discusses cloning of ExtJs objects.

### Edit:

You are getting an extjs object and store it in the `chart` variable. In the second part you are trying to assign the object to the `xtype` property.
You should directly add it to the `items` property like so:

```
win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
    title: 'Layout Window',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [chart]
});
```

But this still "cut" your object and not "copy" it.

### Edit2:

A good way for component copying is creating a function that return an instance of a chart. You can use the same store with the same data.

```
function createChart(store){
    return Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
       width: 400,
       height: 300,
       store: store
    });
}
```

use it like so:

```
win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
    title: 'Layout Window',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [createChart(myStore)]//myStore must be defined
});
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll search and let you know if it works

Comment: I've tried your edit and it does the same as you suspected. As for the "cloning", I used the function and I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`...

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that my chart's series fields and axes are dynamically generated upon user's action, your update results in a empty chart. How can I add an instance of that container inside the window?